# Keep getting "error: Cannot assign to int(64) from iterator''

Tags: chapel

I keep getting an error when trying to do my matrix multiplication. I can't find any documentation on how to fix this error.

Here is my code:

```
var grid : [1..size, 1..size] uint(8);
var grid2 : [1..size, 1..size] uint(8);
var grid3 : [1..size, 1..size] int;
var grid4 : [1..size, 1..size] uint(8);

fillRandom(grid);
fillRandom(grid2);

forall i in 1..size {
    forall k in 1..size {
        grid4 = grid[i,k];
        forall j in 1..size {
            grid3[i,j] += grid4 * grid2[k,j]; //error on this line
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the error:

```
13: error: Cannot assign to int(64) from iterator
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is due to the following line:

```
        grid3[i,j] += grid4 * grid2[k,j]; //error on this line
```

Specifically, since grid4 is an array, `grid4 * grid2[k,j]` represents an iterator expression that represents each element of the array `grid4` multiplied by the scalar `grid2[k,j]`.  Think of it as a virtual `size x size` array of values.

Since the left-hand-side expression, `grid3[i,j]` is just a single scalar rather than something that has size*size elements, the assignment can't be completed.  To make it legal, you'd need to either replace the `grid4` expression with a scalar value or replace the result expression in the assignment with something that has size*size elements.

Knowing that you're trying to express matrix multiplication, my suggestion would be to eliminate grid4 and write your loop as:

```
var grid : [1..size, 1..size] uint(8);
var grid2 : [1..size, 1..size] uint(8);
var grid3 : [1..size, 1..size] int;
```

...

```
forall i in 1..size {
    forall k in 1..size {
        const gridIJ = grid[i,k];
        forall j in 1..size {
            grid3[i,j] += gridIJ * grid2[k,j]; //error on this line
        }
    }
}
```

That is, declare a scalar temporary to store the i,j element within the loop nest.